# Error during Convolutional Neural Network training

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Error using trainNetwork
Unexpected input size: All observations must have the same channel and spatial dimension sizes.

[This is the montage of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BciYC.png)

Here is my Code:

```
clc
clear
close all

% Reading the file with Image Dataset
imgDatasetPath = fullfile(matlabroot, "ImgDataset");
imds = imageDatastore(imgDatasetPath, "IncludeSubfolders", true, ...
    "LabelSource", "foldernames");



% Testing that the file is being read correctly
img = imshow(readimage(imds, 3));
title("Key");



% Splitting data in Training, Validation, and Testing

fracTrainFiles = 0.6;  % 60% of data for Training the network

fracValFiles = 0.2;    % 20% of data for Validate, to prevent overfitting

fracTestFiles = 0.2;   % 20% of data for Testing, to evaluate final performance

[imdsTrain, imdsVal, imdsTest] = splitEachLabel(imds, ...
    fracTrainFiles, fracValFiles,... 
    fracTestFiles, "randomize");



%-----------------------BUILDING NETWORK---------------------------------%



% Number of classes = 2 (Key and Not Key)
NumClasses = 2;



% Creating Convolutional Network Layers
layers = [
    imageInputLayer([200 200 3])  

    convolution2dLayer(3,8, "padding", "same")
    batchNormalizationLayer()
    reluLayer()

    maxPooling2dLayer(2, "stride",2)

    convolution2dLayer(3,16, "padding", "same")
    batchNormalizationLayer()
    reluLayer()

    maxPooling2dLayer(2, "stride",2)

    fullyConnectedLayer(NumClasses)
    softmaxLayer()
    classificationLayer()
    ]



% Setting Training Options

options = trainingOptions("sgdm", ...
    "InitialLearnRate", 0.01, ...             
    "MaxEpochs", 10, ...
    "Shuffle", "every-epoch",...
    "ValidationData", imdsVal,...
    "ValidationFrequency", 30, ...
    "Verbose", false,...
    "Plots", "training-progress");

net = trainNetwork(imdsTrain, layers, options)
```

At first I found that some of the images were not 200x200, or grayscale instead of rgb, but after fixing that issue I am still getting that error.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you probably haven't fix the issue fully?